# How do you send and receive JSON with jQuery.dataTables 1.10 to a ASP.NET WebMethod backend?

Tags: asp.net, ajax, json, datatables, webmethod

Version 1.10 of jQuery DataTables changes a ton of things from the previous versions of DataTables, including how it handles the Ajax requests and responses.

The developers of the library do not have any experience working with an ASP.NET backend, so although some of the nuances of WebMethods have been brought up to them in the past, they apparently didn't consider them in this version.

For example, the `dataSrc` DataTables option should be where we deal with the fact that ASP.NET WebMethods wrap all of their Ajax responses with `{d: [response]}`.

Instead, DataTables only looks at the `dataSrc` setting to find the data property, not the rest of the required response information (`draw`, `recordsTotal`, `recordsFiltered`, and `error`). My memory could be incorrect, but I'm pretty sure the `dataSrc` setting used to handle this just fine.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Below is my solution. There may be an easier way to do this, but the way I setup dataTables below seemed to be most reusable way of sending and receiving JSON to a ASP.NET WebMethod. Please post other ways that have worked for you. Hopefully someone will have a less wonky way of doing the "d" thing.

```
var $table = $('#TableId');
var url = 'page.aspx/WebMethodName';
var extraData = {
    something: 'value1',
    somethingElse: 'value2'
};
```

Event handler handles receiving the data from the server. I move everything from the d property into the root of the object.

```
$table.on('xhr.dt', function (e, settings, json)
                {
                    /// <summary>
                    /// Fix for asp.net WebMethod compatibility.
                    /// If json has a d property, then response came from a WebMethod. 
                    /// DataTables needs the contents of the d property to be in the root.
                    /// </summary>
                    /// <param name="e">The jQuery event object.</param>
                    /// <param name="settings">The jquery.DataTables settings object.</param>
                    /// <param name="json">The data returned from the server.</param>

                    if(json.d)
                    {
                        var data = json.d;

                        // Clear out json.d to free up memory
                        json.d = undefined;

                        $.extend(json, data);
                    }

                    // Note no return - we have to manipulate the data directly in the JSON object.
                    // WHY, OH WHY, CAN'T WE JUST RETURN?
                }
);
```

DataTable initialization. I serialize the data to send to the server as late as possible to give myself plenty of opportunity to add to the request.

```
$table.DataTable({
    ajax: {
        {
            url: url,
            type: 'POST',
            contentType: 'application/json',
            processData: false, // important so the raw data makes it to the beforeSend handler
            beforeSend:function(  jqXHR,  settings )
                {
                    /// <summary>
                    /// Converts to json for transmission and adds any extra data desired.
                    /// </summary>
                    /// <param name="jqXHR">The jqXHR object.</param>
                    /// <param name="settings">The settings object.</param>
                    /// <param name="data">The data that will be sent to the server.</param>

                    var data = settings.data;

                    // I postponed the serialization as long as possible, so this is the
                    // last chance to attach extra data to send along
                    data.extraData = extraData;


                    settings.data = JSON.stringify({ WebMethodParameterName: data });
                }
        }
    }
});
```

On the server side I've created classes to model the structure that dataTables sends and requires as a response. T is the type for each row of data. The DataTablesResponse has a constructor overload which takes the request.draw value and sticks it in the response so I don't have to remember.

```
[WebMethod]
public static DataTablesResponse<T> WebMethodName(DataTablesRequest request)
{
    var response = new DataTablesResponse<T>(request);

    // Do something to get my data
    List<T> results = GetMyData();

    response.data = results;
    return response;
}
```

As a side note, I attempted to post this to the dataTables.net forums, but I can't get it past draft for some reason... so it will live here instead.

Comment: This is my answer. I used the answer your own question option when I created the question. I would love to see if someone has a better answer, but this question was posted mainly to help people with the same problem I had.

Comment: Yes. By the way, you WebMethod isn't supported anymore. You should switch to [ASP.NET Web API](http://www.asp.net/web-api).

Comment: Ah. In that case, no you'll have to stick with WebMethod, or run a separate .NET 4 site. But on another note, Sharepoint 2010 is 5 years old (and basically horrible to use). Obviously it's a big task to upgrade Sharepoint, but you should consider doing it if you're not already. Sharepoint 2013 is a pleasure to use. Or Office 365.

Comment: I agree.. but not my choice. I miss asp.net MVC soooo much!

Comment: Uhh...I don't think Page Methods are going anywhere. I understand you can use Web API but looking at MSDN ScriptManager still supports the EnablePageMethods and there's no note of it being obsolete.

Answer (score 4):

To handle JSON response from the server in format `{d: { data: [] } }`, you can use DataTables initialization option [`dataSrc`](http://datatables.net/reference/option/ajax.dataSrc) as follows `"dataSrc": "d.data"`.
However it only works for client-side processing mode.

**Client-side processing mode only**

```
$('#example').dataTable({
   "ajax": {
      "url": "Default.aspx/GetSearchResults",
      "type": "POST",
      "contentType": "application/json; charset=utf-8",
      "dataType": "json",
      "data": function (d) {
         return JSON.stringify(d);
      },
      "dataSrc": "d.data"
   }
});
```

**Universal solution**
**fot client-side and server-side processing modes**

In server-side processing mode we need to let DataTables access other variables that the server-side script sends, such as `draw`, `recordsTotal`, etc. To do so we need to use callback for [`dataSrc`](http://datatables.net/reference/option/ajax.dataSrc) option and copy  `json.d` properties into `json` and get rid of `d` property.

```
$('#example').dataTable({
   "ajax": {
      "url": "Default.aspx/GetSearchResults",
      "type": "POST",
      "contentType": "application/json; charset=utf-8",
      "dataType": "json",
      "data": function (d) {
         return JSON.stringify(d);
      },
      "dataSrc": function(json){
         for(key in json.d){ json[key] = json.d[key]; }
         delete json['d'];

         return json.data;
      }
   }
});
```

Comment: That only works if you only have the data in the response. If you use server side processing for sorting/filtering/paging, it does not work.

Comment: That won't help with the other required server side values. The properties draw, recordsTotal, recordsFiltered, and error all reside in d as well. The dataSrc property only points to where the data value is.

Comment: @Somna, I see what you mean now, that makes sense. I will update my answer.

Comment: THIS IS THE SOLUTION. GREAT

Answer (score 0):

You can use EnablePageMethods on the ScriptManager and call them directly from the PageMethods object which will not have the returned data nested in .d.

Answer (score 0):

You can use dataFilter function in your ajax call to strip the d property. Note if your dataType is json, you need stringify your object back to string as the ajax will parse the returned data to json again.

```
ajax: {
                type: "POST",
                contentType: "application/json; charset=utf-8",
                url: "...",
                dataType: 'json',
                dataFilter: function (data) {
                    //data is raw string, convert to json object first
                    //must return string if the dataType is set to json and the jQuery ajax will parse the returned data again
                    var msg = jq.parseJSON(data);
                    if (msg.hasOwnProperty('d')) {
                        return JSON.stringify(msg.d);
                    } else
                        return data;
                }
            }
```

Answer (score 0):

Custom return like d string, just format response

```
ajax =  {
            "url": currentPage+`/method`,
            "contentType": "application/json; charset=utf-8",
            "type": "Get",
            "dataType": "json",
            "dataSrc": function(json){
                let r = JSON.parse(json.d)
                return r;
              }
            }
```