# jquery datatable server side processing .net Core

Tags: jquery, asp.net-core, datatables

i'm using jquery datatable with .net core to build grids
i'm using server side processing
i'm using this package [GitHub Link](https://github.com/fingers10/JqueryDataTablesServerSide)

the problem i get request unknown parameter 'CivilID' for row 0 column 0

Client Side

```
var table = $('#tblClient').DataTable({
    language: {
        processing: "Loading Data...",
        zeroRecords: "No matching records found"
    },
    processing: true,
    serverSide: true,
    orderCellsTop: true,
    autoWidth: true,
    deferRender: true,
    dom: '<tr>',
    ajax: {
        type: "POST",
        url: '/Client/LoadTable/',
        contentType: "application/json; charset=utf-8",
        async: true,

        data: function(data) {
            let additionalValues = [];
            additionalValues[0] = "Additional Parameters 1";
            additionalValues[1] = "Additional Parameters 2";
            data.AdditionalValues = additionalValues;
            return JSON.stringify(data);
        }
    },

    columns: [
        {
            title: "CivilID",
            data: "CivilID",
        },
        {
            title: "LastName",
            data: "LastName"
        }, {
            title: "FirstName",
            data: "FirstName"
        }
    ]
});
```

Server side

```
public async Task<IActionResult> LoadTable([FromBody]DTParameters param) {
    try {
        // var data = await _demoService.GetDataAsync(param);
        List<ClientViewModel> ClientsList = new List<ClientViewModel>();

        var result = HttpContext.Session.GetString("AllClients");
        ClientsList = JsonConvert.DeserializeObject<List<ClientViewModel>>(result);

        var json= new JsonResult(new DTResult<ClientViewModel> {
            draw = param.Draw,
            data = ClientsList,
            recordsFiltered = ClientsList.Count,
            recordsTotal = ClientsList.Count
        });
        return json;
    } catch (Exception e) {

    }
}
```

Data
[image]

the data is in the picture is for the ClientViewModel
it is the same names in the client side 
what i'm missing 
thank you

Comment: Add `'dataSrc': function ( json ) { console.log(json); return json.data; }` as an option after `data` and post the output here for at least one record. It is possible .NET wraps the response in `{d: { /* response */ }}`. See [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/31064052/3549014) if that's the case.

Comment: @Maher Khalil. Did you try with updated Nuget Package that you have mentioned in the link? The updated package has different model name for request and response. Check the docs in the GitHub link you gave mentioned.

Comment: Can you share the table html? Please check the demo solution in the following link. [JQuery DataTables Demo](https://github.com/fingers10/JqueryDataTablesServerSideDemo)

Comment: Refer the following article [Article explaining the nuget package you used](https://www.c-sharpcorner.com/article/jquery-datatables-with-asp-net-core-server-side-dynamic-multiple-column-searchin/)

Answer (score 0):

Add this on the startup.cs

```
services.AddMvc()
        .AddJsonOptions(options =>
         {
             options.SerializerSettings.ContractResolver
                 = new Newtonsoft.Json.Serialization.DefaultContractResolver();
         });
```

Answer (score 0):

Use camelcase format in JSON return like this

```
columns: [
        {
            title: "CivilID",
            data: "civilID",
        },
        {
            title: "LastName",
            data: "lastName"
        }, {
            title: "FirstName",
            data: "firstName"
        }
    ]
```